# Laravel 5.4 collection sortByDesc not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections

I have two queries with Eloquent which I collect and merge and after i do `sortByDesc` but it's not sorting collection.

```
$f_games = collect(Game::with('fUser', 'sUser')->where('first_user_id', Auth::user()->id)>get());
$s_games = collect(Game::with('fUser', 'sUser')->where('second_user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get());

$response = $f_games->merge($s_games)->sortByDesc('id');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `values()` at the end of sorting, as discussed in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sortby)

```
$gameCollection = collect($game);

$sorted = $gameCollection->sortByDesc('date');

return $sorted->values()->all();
```

In you case it should be

```
$response = $f_games->merge($s_games)->sortByDesc('id')->values();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sortByDesc` method sorts the collection by field that belongs to some eloquent relation in your model.

If you are trying to sort collection with `sortByDesc` for model itself ( your current object of model), please user `orderBy` rather than `sortByDesc`

***Example***:

For model itself

```
{$collection_list = $this->model_name->orderBy('field_name','DESC')->get();}
```

For relations that will be lazy loaded in views

```
{$collection_list = $this->model_name->get()->sortBy('table_name.field_name', SORT_REGULAR, true);}
```

***Note***: `sortByDesc` internally called `sortBy()` with descending order,
       true means Descending Order and false means Ascending Order.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to wrap in `collect()`, `$f_games` and `$s_games` will be collection without additional wrapping:

```
$f_games = Game::with('fUser', 'sUser')->where('first_user_id', Auth::user()->id)>get();
$s_games = Game::with('fUser', 'sUser')->where('second_user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
$response = $f_games->merge($s_games)->sortByDesc('id');
```

But the best way is:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;

$f_s_games = Game::with('fUser', 'sUser')
             ->where('first_user_id', $user_id)
             ->orWhere('second_user_id',$user_id)
             ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
             ->get();
```