# print results in descending order

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I need to print results in a decreasing way

**controller**:

```
$servicios = \App\Models\Eventos::All()->sortByDesc('hora');
```

**blade.php**

```
@foreach ($servicios as $hoy)
    <tr>
        <td class="checkbox-column text-center">{{$hoy->id}} </td>
        <td>{{$hoy->hora}}</td>
        <td>{{$hoy->titulo}}</td>
        <td>{{$hoy->personal}}</td>
        <td>{{$hoy->servicio}}</td>
        <td>{{$hoy->descripcion}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <span class="shadow-none {{$hoy->prioridad}}">
                @if($hoy->prioridad == 'badge badge-primary') 
                    Normal
                @elseif($hoy->prioridad == 'badge badge-warning') 
                    Prioridad
                @elseif($hoy->prioridad == 'badge badge-success') 
                    Personal
                @elseif ($hoy->prioridad == 'badge badge-danger') 
                    Urgente
                @endif
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

[image]

The problem is that it does not print with the foreach with the DESC order

Comment: $servicios return result correct?

Comment: returns correct result, but does not order the field 'time'

Comment: Try to avoid sorting in PHP as much as possible if the DB can do it for you... Instead of `all` and then `sort`, you have to first sort and replace `all` with `get`, normal eloquent usage.

Comment: $servicios = Eventos::get()->sortByDesc('hora')->values()->all(); tried this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765120/laravel-5-4-collection-sortbydesc-not-working

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/LcMyzXV.png  keep printing out of order

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$servicios = \App\Models\Eventos::latest('hora')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `orderByDesc`

```
$servicios = \App\Models\Eventos::orderByDesc('hora')->get();
```

Comment: @jererosas what data type is in hora in database table

Comment: this table "hora" is varchar

Comment: @jererosas expeted out put is 12:00,12:00,10:00,10:00 right

Comment: correct, but right now the output it prints is 10:00 12:00 12:00 10:00 10:00

Comment: definitely not .i have verified in my local system.clear cache by runing command php artisan optimize

Comment: sorry, I already found the problem. when printing the record ID it would sort everything that way and skip the order

Answer (score 0):

You can use orderBy() as follows:

```
use App\Models\Eventos;

$servicios = Eventos::All()->orderBy('hora', 'DESC')->get();
```